# Can I overlay a matplotlib contour over a seaborn heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a heatmap done in seaborn and a contour plotted via matplotlib.pyplot.

Is it possible to overlay the two?

Comment: Post some code.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seaborn uses matplotlib under the hood.  You can combine seaborn plots as if they were directly created by matplotlib.  To draw onto the same subplot, the same `ax` should be used. To align the centers of the heatmap cells with the contour lines, you need to add `0.5` to the x and the y coordinates.

Here is an example to get you started:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter

data = gaussian_filter(np.random.randn(20, 40), sigma=2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 5))
sns.heatmap(data=data, cbar_kws={'pad': 0.02}, ax=ax)
ax.contour(np.arange(.5, data.shape[1]), np.arange(.5, data.shape[0]), data, colors='yellow')
plt.show()
```

[image: combining sns.heatmap with plt.contour]